# Is the graph plot of y-axis $= \cos(x)$ and x-axis $= \sin(x)$ a circle?

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I'm interested in knowing how would the graph plot of Y-axis $= \cos(x)$ and X-axis $= \sin(x)$ might look like. Will it form a circle ?

Comment: What you are describing is what is known as a **parametrization** of a circle of radius $1$. Usually $x$ is not used for the parameter, because it is also the $x$ coordinate, so that presents issues. The most common variable chosen for a parameter is $t$, so we have: $$y=\cos(t)$$ and $$x=\sin(t)$$ with $$0 \leq t <2\pi$$

This is called a parametrization of a curve, and this particular curve is, as you predicted, a circle.

Answer (score 1):

They should be $Y=\cos t, X=\sin t$, then by squaring and adding you get $X^2+Y^2=1,$
which is a circle. Use $t$ in place of $x$, it may comfuse one.